# Running a script from gem in GitHub in RVM

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, rvm

Can anyone help me walk through what I'm doing wrong here? This is my first go w/ Ruby so any help would be appreciated:

1. I've installed RVM and executing it through Terminal
2. I'm trying to run the script detailed in this post from GitHub:
   https://github.com/michiels/helpscout-export
3. I was successfully able to install the gem 'HelpScout'
4. When I run **ruby export.rb MY_api_key** I get this error message:

   ruby: No such file or directory -- export.rb (LoadError)

Anyone have any insight? Here's my current gem environment:

```
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x86_64-darwin15.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/stevekrause/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
     - /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
     - /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin
     - /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
     - /Users/stevekrause/.rvm/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
     - /Users/stevekrause/anaconda/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: Have you donnloaded the`export.rb` script? You need the Gem _and_ the script (the script uses the Gem). Either [clone the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/), or just copy the [contents of `export.rb`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michiels/helpscout-export/master/export.rb) into a new file. Then run the command from the same directory as the script file.

Comment: Aha! Thanks Matt. I've copied the repository successfully, and export.rb exists. Now, I'm still getting the same Load Error message -- how do I run the command from the same directory?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! Thanks Matt!